# Field error in object 'user' on field 'userProfiles': rejected value [3];

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jpa

I have downloaded a working demo which working perfectly fine while I ran it. But when I have just made my way and I am using same page and functionality with registration page and then I submitting the form I am getting error:

```
[Field error in object 'user' on field 'userProfiles': rejected value [3]; codes [typeMismatch.user.userProfiles,typeMismatch.userProfiles,typeMismatch.java.util.Set,typeMismatch]; arguments 
    [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.userProfiles,userProfiles]; arguments []; default message [userProfiles]]; default message 
[Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Set' for property 'userProfiles'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type 
[com.idev.tpt.model.UserProfile] for property 'userProfiles[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]
```

**JSP File**:

```
<form:form id="userForm" action="newuser" modelAttribute="user">
    <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <form:input type="text" path="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control input-sm" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form:input type="text" path="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control input-sm" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${edit}">
                <form:input type="text" path="ssoId" id="ssoId" placeholder="SSO ID" class="form-control input-sm" disabled="true" />
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <form:input type="text" path="ssoId" id="ssoId" placeholder="SSO ID" class="form-control input-sm" />
                <div class="has-error">
                    <form:errors path="ssoId" class="help-inline" />
                </div>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form:input type="password" path="password" id="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control input-sm" />
        <div class="has-error">
            <form:errors path="password" class="help-inline" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form:input type="text" path="email" id="email" placeholder="email" class="form-control input-sm" />
        <div class="has-error">
            <form:errors path="email" class="help-inline" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <form:select path="userProfiles" items="${roles}" multiple="true" itemValue="id" itemLabel="type" class="form-control input-sm" />
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="form-group">
                                            <textarea class="form-control" id="prop_note" name="note" placeholder="Note" ></textarea>
                                        </div> -->
    <p class="demo-button btn-toolbar">
        <span id="warningLbl" class="label label-warning" style="display: none;"></span>
        <button id="propAddBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save</button>
        <button id="propUpdateBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="display: none;">Update</button>&nbsp;
        <button id="propClearBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="display: none;">Clear</button>
    </p>
    <br>
</form:form>
```

**controller**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newUser(ModelMap model) {
        User user = new User();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("edit", false);
        model.addAttribute("roles", userProfileService.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "registration";
    }

    /**
     * This method will be called on form submission, handling POST request for
     * saving user in database. It also validates the user input
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result,
            ModelMap model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        if(!userService.isUserSSOUnique(user.getId(), user.getSsoId())){
            FieldError ssoError =new FieldError("user","ssoId",messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.ssoId", new String[]{user.getSsoId()}, Locale.getDefault()));
            result.addError(ssoError);
            return "registration";
        }

        userService.saveUser(user);

        model.addAttribute("success", "User " + user.getFirstName() + " "+ user.getLastName() + " registered successfully");
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        //return "success";
        return "registrationsuccess";
    }
```

**Model** :

```
package com.websystique.springmvc.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="APP_USER")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="SSO_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String ssoId;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="PASSWORD", nullable=false)
    private String password;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME", nullable=false)
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="LAST_NAME", nullable=false)
    private String lastName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="EMAIL", nullable=false)
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "APP_USER_USER_PROFILE", 
             joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, 
             inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_PROFILE_ID") })
    private Set<UserProfile> userProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>();

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSsoId() {
        return ssoId;
    }

    public void setSsoId(String ssoId) {
        this.ssoId = ssoId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Set<UserProfile> getUserProfiles() {
        return userProfiles;
    }

    public void setUserProfiles(Set<UserProfile> userProfiles) {
        this.userProfiles = userProfiles;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((ssoId == null) ? 0 : ssoId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof User))
            return false;
        User other = (User) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (ssoId == null) {
            if (other.ssoId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!ssoId.equals(other.ssoId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * DO-NOT-INCLUDE passwords in toString function.
     * It is done here just for convenience purpose.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", ssoId=" + ssoId + ", password=" + password
                + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName
                + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

}
```

I am also using the same model provided in the demo. I didn't change anything in the model also not change related to jsp and controller. I don't understand why I am getting an error I am using the same way as like in a demo.

**User profile**

```
package com.websystique.springmvc.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_PROFILE")
public class UserProfile implements Serializable{

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id; 

    @Column(name="TYPE", length=15, unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String type = UserProfileType.USER.getUserProfileType();

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((type == null) ? 0 : type.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof UserProfile))
            return false;
        UserProfile other = (UserProfile) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (type == null) {
            if (other.type != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!type.equals(other.type))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserProfile [id=" + id + ", type=" + type + "]";
    }
}
```

**user profile converter**

```
package com.websystique.springmvc.converter;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.websystique.springmvc.model.UserProfile;
import com.websystique.springmvc.service.UserProfileService;

/**
 * A converter class used in views to map id's to actual userProfile objects.
 */
@Component
public class RoleToUserProfileConverter implements Converter<Object, UserProfile>{

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RoleToUserProfileConverter.class);

    @Autowired
    UserProfileService userProfileService;

    /**
     * Gets UserProfile by Id
     * @see org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter#convert(java.lang.Object)
     */
    public UserProfile convert(Object element) {
        Integer id = Integer.parseInt((String)element);
        UserProfile profile= userProfileService.findById(id);
        logger.info("Profile : {}",profile);
        return profile;
    }

}
```

**Updated**

one more thing while I printing the form data using model getter method getUserProfiles() I am getting blank data so I think it's not binding the selected value.but any other column I am printing it will perfectly bind.

Comment: please share the complete stacktrace.

Comment: 1. Can you also please share the value of ${roles}?
2. Can you try deleting 'multiple' attribute of the select tag?
3. If it still doesn't work, try using path='userProfile[0]' without using the 'multiple' attribute.

Comment: Hi, @sbsatter and NKR please see the discussion I have shred all the details over there also I have resolved my issue by integrating demo again. and now my demo is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

After your comment I updated my reply:

Probably the problem is in JSP code. When application invokes the `saveUser()` method in your controller, a new User object is created. But because you have `UserProfile` type in User object the application has to know how to create `UserProfile` from String (when passed from `<form:select path="userProfiles">`).

Either you add a custom converter from String to `UserProfile` or create an `UserDTO` class with Java standard types and use it in your Controller save operation. Code will be something similar to:

```
public String saveUser(@Valid UserDTO dto, ...) {
    User user = createUserFromDTO(dto);
    userService.saveUser(user);
}
```

---

If you have a converter defined, check if it's added to the `FormatterRegistry` during application configuration.

Also make sure, that you have the `UserProfile` entity correctly defined with JPA annotations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. as i have mentioned in the question that i have a working demo and also i have used the same file copy-pasting to new project i am facing an issue.

Comment: For your suggestion, I have used the same user profile which i have in working demo i didn't change anything.

Comment: Tried to refine my answer based on your comments

Comment: Please see the edited question I have added my user profile  class

Comment: I think the problem is not in JPA. It's in JSP side. Does the error shown when you try to save your user? See my updated answer for details.

Comment: definitely, it's a JSP side issue but I can't figure it out. I already have a converter in my page in working demo it's going to convert method but in my demo, it shouldn't because it will not bind the form I am getting the blank value while printing the user profile to a controller.

Comment: Can you include example code of the converter configuration as well?

Comment: please see my updated question I have added converter configuration also added a comment that I think to be useful.

Comment: I guess your example is from here: http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-and-spring-security-4-integration-example/. Make sure, that you have your `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and especially check if `addFormatters` is called and converter is added to your `FormatterRegistry`. Either add a log message or use the debugger to check if this method is called.

Comment: yes right the example running perfectly fine but when i integrate with my project i am getting the error while saving data using the same page for adding new user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170616/discussion-between-vimaldev-and-oresztesz).